# How are trades performed on ships at sea factored into GDP calculations?

Tags: macroeconomics, gdp, national-income

When a ship is less than $12$ nautical miles from a country's coast, it's in that country's domestic territory, however, on the high seas, it's in the country in which it's registered. So if a sale is made on board, which country's GDP is it included in? How do we account for these sales? The contribution may seem small, but according to 2018 figures, it's a massive industry, with a value of over 45 billion dollars.

Comment: I think you may be overestimating the precisions with which GDP is calculated. Can you give us a link to the $45B figure?

Comment: https://www.fool.com/investing/2019/07/28/how-big-is-the-cruise-industry.aspx

Comment: That's a figure for the entire cruise market, not for goods sold on ships on the high seas.

Comment: I don't have any other figures, sorry

Comment: https://www.statista.com/statistics/204545/cruise-revenue-per-passenger-2011-by-type/

Comment: according to this link , the average spending in 2015 onboard was ~$400, and  23 million travelled by cruise ships in 2015, which gives a figure of atleast 10 billion